# Locally run Google App Engine Flex with Memcache?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, memcached

I am trying to run google app engine with memcache locally with `go run *.go` and I am getting the following response:

> service bridge HTTP failed: Post http://appengine.googleapis.internal:10001/rpc_http: dial tcp: lookup appengine.googleapis.internal: no such host**

What is the proper way to run locally?

Comment: Which Memcache library are you trying to use?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/memcache/using

Answer (score 0):

The [library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/memcache/using) that you are trying to use is a App Engine standard environment library that is not available in the flexible environment. The flexible environment is built on top of Compute Engine and a very different system. You could try using [MemoryStore for Redis](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex). You also might be able to break your application into microservices. An App Engine project can have services on different runtime environments (mix of flex/std, mix of languages), but you'll have to be careful about how you communicate and work across the services. Its not necessarily a trivial thing to rearchitect your app though.